# A problem on bivariate random variables

Tags: distributions, density-function

Suppose we have absolutely continuous random vectors $X=(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$. And we have $Y_i=a_iX_i+b_i$, and $a_i>0, b_i\geq 0$ $i=1,2$ . Let ${F}$ be a distribution function such that
${F}_X(x_1,x_2)=P(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2).$
We know that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}F_X(x_1,x_2)=f_X(x_1,x_2).$

Now, \begin{align}
F_Y(y_1,y_2)&=P(Y_1\leq y_1,Y_2\leq y_2)\\
&=P(a_1X_1+b_1\leq y_1,a_2X_2+b_2\leq y_2)\\
&=P(X_1\leq (y_1-b_1)/a_1,X_2\leq (y_2-b_2)/a_2)\\
&=F_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1,(y_2-b_2)/a_2)\\
&=F_X(x_1,x_2)
\end{align}
Form here can we say that $f(y_1,y_2)=f(x_1,x_2)$?
Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Ask yourself whether the univariate version of this is true.  It is not, but exploring *why* it is false will point you towards a correct formula.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, when $\mathbf X\mapsto \mathbf Y$ via a one-one onto transformation, say $y_i:= g_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n), $ and $h_i:=g_i^{-1}, $ then if $\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial y_j}$ are continuous for all $i, j\in\{1, 2,\ldots, n\}, $ then $$f_\mathbf Y(\mathbf y) =f_\mathbf X(h_1(\mathbf y), \ldots, h_n(\mathbf y) ) |\mathrm J(\mathbf y) |, $$ where $\mathrm J(\mathbf y) :=\det\left(\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial y_j}\right) . $

Comment: Truly this is still one of my favourite results in mathematical statistics. I also like the [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula).

Comment: I think the general intuitive essence can be seen when dealing with linear transformation of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n, $ @Galen.

Comment: @Galen Is there any name of above formula. Where can I find this and similar thongs?

Comment: The terms to look up include "change of variables" and "transformations of random variables". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function), [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Random_Variables), and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities).